# I am selecting a description field from an asp.net database with bullet point formatting and trying to update a field on the system I

Tags: php, sql, asp.net, pdo

in my php program I am selecting a formatted (with bullet points) field from my storefront which is ASP.net.  Then I want to store that information into a database on the system I (as400).  I have had to break the field apart and then concatenate it back together to update the 400.  Not sure why this had to be done - is there a limit as to how much data php can process?

But I get the error message:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation:
0 [IBM][System i Access ODBC Driver][DB2 for i5/OS]SQL0010 - String constant beginning '&lt;ul&g' not delimited. (SQLPrepare[0] at ext\pdo_odbc\odbc_driver.c:206)' in C:\wamp\www\LIID\DIT\apps\PCSSKUMasterLoad\PCSSKUProc.php on line 120
```

Here is my code:

```
$query = $conn->prepare("select Product.Name, Product.Description from Product, ProductVariant where Product.Published = 1 and Product.ProductID = ProductVariant.ProductID and ProductVariant.ManufacturerPartNumber = '$SFITEM' ");   

$query->execute();

while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { 

    $Name = fixquote($row['Name']); 
    $DESC = fixquote($row['Description']);
    $PUB = $row['Published'] ; 

//********************************************************//
// Add to AS400 Contact file
//*******************************************************//

$SKFAM = $Name;

$SDESC = trim($DESC);

$SKSKUD = mb_substr($DESC,0,272,'iso-8859-1');
$SKSKUD1 = trim($SKSKUD);
$SKSKUD2 = mb_substr($DESC,272,272,'iso-8859-1');
$SKSKUD2 = trim($SKSKUD2);
$SKSKUD3 = mb_substr($DESC,544,272,'iso-8859-1');
$SKSKUD3 = trim($SKSKUD3);
$SKSKUD4 = mb_substr($DESC,816,200,'iso-8859-1');
$SKSKUD4 = trim($SKSKUD4);

$SKSKUDa = trim($SKSKUD1).trim($SKSKUD2);
$SKSKUDb = trim($SKSKUDa).trim($SKSKUD3);
$SKSKUD = trim($SKSKUDb).trim($SKSKUD4);

try {
 $db2 = new PDO($db_hostname, $db_user, $db_pass);
 }
catch (PDOException $e) {
echo $e->getMessage();
}
$db2->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$query400 = $db2->prepare("UPDATE $liblp.PCPSKUM SET SKFAM = '$SKFAM', SKSKUD = '$SKSKUD', SKACTV = 'Y' WHERE SKSKU = '$SFPROD' ");


$query400->execute();
```

I get many records updated.  It appears to blow up when the converted characters are split between the fields.

Thanks for any help you can give me!

Comment: 99.999999% probability that you have an [sql injection attack](http://bobby-tables.com) vulnerability... and since you're using PDO exactly the WRONG way, you really really REALLY need to go read up on how to use a prepared statement properly.

Comment: Please don't tag with both MySQL and SQL Server.  These different products often require different solutions.

Comment: Sorry, destination-data....I am new to this.

Comment: And thank you soooooo much for your helpful, kind comments Marc B!  Way to help out someone new to php.  I would have thought if you saw something wrong in my code you would have offered a helpful hand versus what you gave!!!!  Which was just insult on top of insult.  So much for help....